# magento2 text description is displaying question mark

Tags: magento2

```
Cut pile�is a process of�carpet�that is shaved, revealing the ends of the�carpet�fibre.�Cut
```

My text description is displaying question mark.

Following is the code being used to display description

```
<p><?= $_product->getData('paragraph_1'); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are characters in the source text with an unrecognised encoding.

If this text is originating from a file you need to check the encoding or you need to fix the original text by looking more closely at what these characters are and replacing them.

You could also try filtering out non ascii characters when you display the text in your template:

```
echo filter_var($_product->getData('paragraph_1'), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to filter your html content.

```
<?php Package\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
         * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
         */
        protected $_filterProvider;
        
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        }
    
        public function getFilteredContent($value='')
        {
            $html = $this->filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($value);
            return $html;
        }
}
```

Use "getFilteredContent($value)" anywhere like below and pass your html in argument. I have used it in phtml file.

```
<?php $helper = $this->helper('Package\Module\Helper\Data'); ?>
<?php $content = $_product->getData('paragraph_1'); ?>
<?php $filteredHtml = $helper->getFilteredContent($content); ?>
```

Now please check by print that variable value like below.

```
<?php echo $filteredHtml; ?>
```